# matplotlib custom markers

Tags: python, matplotlib

I would like markers such as empty squares with +, or x, or ., or anything inside with adjustable thickness; In fact the ones like in Origin. It seems that it needs customisation.

code example:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

plt.plot(np.arange(10) ** 2,
         'k-',
         marker = 's',
         mfc = 'none',
         lw = 2,
         mew = 2,
         ms = 20)
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Using `text`, you can use any character available in your fonts.  You need to iterate through them yourself though, and I don't think that you can get continuous control over their linewidth (though, of course, you can select 'bold', etc, if available).

[image]

```
from numpy import *
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

symbols = [u'\u2B21', u'\u263A', u'\u29C6', u'\u2B14', u'\u2B1A', u'\u25A6', u'\u229E', u'\u22A0', u'\u22A1', u'\u20DF']

x = arange(10.)
y = arange(10.)

plt.figure()
for i, symbol in enumerate(symbols):
    y2 = y + 4*i
    plt.plot(x, y2, 'g')
    for x0, y0 in zip(x, y2):
        plt.text(x0, y0, symbol, fontname='STIXGeneral', size=30, va='center', ha='center', clip_on=True)

plt.show()
```

You can also use `plot` directly, though the rendering doesn't look quite as good and you don't have quite as much control over the characters.

```
plt.figure()
for i, symbol in enumerate(symbols):
    y2 = y + 4*i
    plt.plot(x, y2, 'g')
    marker = "$%s$" % symbol
    plt.plot(x, y2, 'k', marker=marker, markersize=30)
```

[image]

Comment: looks good, but that's a pity to use pyplot.text() instead of pyplot.plot() to plot.

Comment: You can use plot (see edit), but for some reason I don't understand, the rendering isn't as nice.  If it were me, I'd just make a little function called `plot_text` that would iterate `text`.

Comment: I tried plt.plot(np.arange(10) ** 2, marker = u'\u2B21'); it returns an error message: UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\u2b21' in position 0: ordinal not in range(128)

Comment: ok, now I tried with dollar signs; it works nicely. Where are specified these font codes? are there some more?

Comment: Yes, there are many, many font codes.  There are over 100,000 unicode characters defined, and each font has a subset of these.  To view these for a font, there are specific font browsers, but I usually just use a word processor, select the font I'd like to use, and then use Insert | Special Character... or a menu option like that, which will pull up a dialog box that shows all the symbols that are defined in the font, and also shows the unicode value for each symbol. To find a font with a specific symbol, just google, (eg, "unicode snowflake").

Answer (score 3):

Is this what you want?

[image: Custom markers by overplotting]

I did this by overplotting thus:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

plt.plot(np.arange(10) ** 2,
         'k-',
         marker = 's',
         mfc = 'none',
         lw = 2,
         mew = 2,
         ms = 20)

plt.plot(np.arange(10) ** 2 + 20,
         'k-',
         marker = '+',
         mfc = 'none',
         lw = 2,
         mew = 2,
         ms = 20)
plt.plot(np.arange(10) ** 2 + 20,
         'k-',
         marker = 's',
         mfc = 'none',
         lw = 2,
         mew = 2,
         ms = 20)
plt.show()
```

Comment: Yes, it is a bit of a hack. @tom10's solution is better :)