# How to create single-headed arrow marker with rotation in Matplotlib?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I want a single-headed arrow (<--) as a marker with rotation. I should be able to generate a rotated single-headed arrow at (x,y) with a given angle. With the code below, I can rotate the standard markers. However, I do not know how to do the same for single-headed arrow (<--). I want to use this marker as a visual representation of how a 2D point is oriented in space.

matplotlib version: 2.2.5 (this cannot be updated)

[image]

```
    import matplotlib as mpl
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

    for i, val in enumerate([0, 30, 60, 90]):
        rotated_marker = mpl.markers.MarkerStyle(marker="^")
        rotated_marker._transform = rotated_marker.get_transform().rotate_deg(val)
        plt.scatter((i), (0), marker=rotated_marker)

    plt.show()
```

Answer (score 1):

As per the answer here: [Down arrow symbol in matplotlib](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16861339/down-arrow-symbol-in-matplotlib/36898228#36898228), symbols can be specified using unicode. Check the code below:

```
import matplotlib as mpl
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Template:Unicode_chart_Arrows
arrow = u'$\u2191$'

for i, val in enumerate([0,90,180,270,360]):
    rotated_marker = mpl.markers.MarkerStyle(marker=arrow)
    rotated_marker._transform = rotated_marker.get_transform().rotate_deg(val)
    plt.scatter((i), (0), marker=rotated_marker, s=150, facecolors='none', edgecolors='b')

plt.show()
```

[image]